# Block on file creation in java (or scala)

Tags: java, scala, file-io

**High level question**: Is there some API call in java (or scala) that will let me block, waiting for a file to be created, without polling?  Or is there *anything* related to the file system that I can block on?

**A few (largely irrelevant) details**: I have a process that I run several instances of at a time, each doing part of a list of work that needs to be done.  The instances may start at different times, and the list of work may change in the interim, and it doesn't really seem feasible to have the processes communicate with each other explicitly*.  The only communication these processes have with each other is through the file system.  So, I would like to have a mechanism for one of the processes to recognize that another process has already started (but not finished) a piece of work that the current process depends on, and block, waiting for the other process to finish.

* I don't really want to have a server running that schedules the work; that's too complicated for what I need.  And the server would need to be polling the filesystem for updates, anyway, because the list of work to be done is in the filesystem and may change at any time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 7 there's [`Watchable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Watchable.html) (and related classes and interfaces in the package `java.nio.file`) which you can use to monitor file system events, using the underlying operating system's features instead of directly polling for these events.

You can use this, for example, to get events for files being created, deleted and modified on the file system.

To ensure that a second process doesn't pick up the file before the first process has finished writing to it, you can let the first process first use a temporary name for the file, and then rename it when it's done. The second process can then get notified when the file is renamed.

Here is an example:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Temp");

// Watch for files and directories being created in C:\\Temp
// (also triggers when file is renamed)
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

// Wait until an event happens
WatchKey key = watchService.take();

// Look at the events that were signaled on the key
for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
    System.out.println(event.kind() + " " + event.context());
}

// Stop receiving events
key.cancel();
```